# Solr sort by key value

Tags: solr

I want to sort the results from Solr by key value.

Here is my scenario:

We have n products, we have m product groups.

1 product can have m product groups 1 product group has n products.

So we have a n:m relation.

Standard: the product has a sort index of 0 per product group there can be 3 Products with a sort index of 1, 2 or 3. 3 should be the first result, 2 the second, 1 the third and then the rest.

Warning: One Product can have a sort index > 0 in multiple product Groups.

Question: How should I index this information? And how should I do the sort in the query to Solr?

Comment: is there any possibility of filtering by product groups and then sort it by products?

Comment: Use the product group name as a custom field name (prefixed with `product_group_` for example) and use the sort index as the value.

Comment: Actual i do filter by product group, so it is possible but how should i then sort it by the sort index on the product group?

Comment: "Use the product group name as a custom field name (prefixed with product_group_ for example) and use the sort index as the value." This is not possible, because the product groups are dynamic and infinite.